# Usage of Measure change?

Tags: android

Could anyone plz tell what is the callback will be called when the screen orientation gets changed ?

Answer (score 2):

By default your Activity is destroyed and recreated on orientation change. Check out the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) sections. What exactly do you want to do on configuration change?

Comment: It's a shame that the list of previous, similar questions which pop up when you're about to post a question here doesn't include a google search. It would spare us a lot of these "too lazy to look for myself" questions, and would really plz (sic) me.